# Setting title as an attribute on a web component triggers maximum callstack

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, web-component

I'm working on a navigation link web component. One of the properties that I want to set on the component is the title. It seems that this is somehow triggering a maximum callstack error. Should I avoid `title` at all? I could use `caption` instead.

**First error**

`Class 'NavLinkCmp' incorrectly extends base class 'HTMLElement'.
  Property 'title' is private in type 'NavLinkCmp' but not in type 'HTMLElement'.`

**Second error**

```
nav-link.cmp.ts:72 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
    at HTMLElement.attributeChangedCallback (nav-link.cmp.ts:72)
```

**navigator-cmp.ts**

```
<nav-link-cmp href="${link.url}" fa-icon="${link.icon}" 
    title="${link.title}" description="${link.description}">
</nav-link-cmp>
```

**nav-link-cmp.ts**

```
export class NavLinkCmp extends HTMLElement {

    // State
    private title: string;

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.render();
    }

    render() {
        this.innerHTML = `
        <div class="info">
            <div class="title">${this.title}</div>
        </div>
        `;
    }

    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ['title'];
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(name: string, oldValue: string, newValue: string) {
        this.title = newValue
    }

}

// Component
require('./nav-link.cmp.scss');
window.customElements.define('nav-link-cmp', NavLinkCmp);
```

Comment: Maybe removing the private?

Comment: I had to add it because of the first error

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
attributeChangedCallback(name: string, oldValue: string, newValue: string) {
  if (oldValue !== newValue) {
    this.title = newValue;
  }
}
```

If `oldValue` and `newValue` are the same then there is no need to set the property again.

If you do then it changes the attribute, which then calls `attributeChangedCallback` again and loops forever.

Comment: Could be useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

the infite loop is caused by the change of the *'title'* value in the attributeChangedCallback.
as this function is called on every changes on the *title* attribute, its called over an over...

why can't you use the parent class *title* property directly ?